# How to remove a single value from an array in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I want to remove the first instance of the lowest value in the array.

```
arr = [1,2,3,1,2,3]
arr.reject {|i| i == arr.min}
#=> [2,3,2,3]
```

But my code removes all instances of the lowest value in the array. I want a result such that:

```
[...]
#=> [2,3,1,2,3]
```

What's the most elegant solution to this problem?

Comment: `arr[0...min_index] + arr[min_index + 1..-1]`

Comment: Does the order matter? If not, `arr.sort.drop(1)` can deal with it.

Answer (score 3):

On first blush, here are a couple of options:

```
arr.delete_at(arr.index(arr.min))
# or less readable but still valid
arr.delete_at arr.index arr.min
```

```
arr.delete_at(arr.each_with_index.min[1])
# or
arr.delete_at(arr.each_with_index.min.pop)
# or
arr.delete_at(arr.each_with_index.min.last)
```

The first is less code and more readable but makes two passes through the list instead of one. I have doubts as to whether any other construct will surpass option #1 in elegance, as ugly as it may (or may not?) be.

Note that both choices crash on an empty array. Here's a safer version:

```
arr.delete_at arr.index(arr.min) || 0
```

Comment: Would upvote your response but I don't have enough kudos to do so! Thanks for taking the time to reply.

I also found a good solution on Code Kata
```
arr.reject.with_index { |_,i| i == arr.index(arr.min) }
```

Courtesy of 'Instu': https://www.codewars.com/users/Insti

Comment: Thanks! The issue with that solution is that the nested `.index`/`.min` calls wreck the time complexity (O(n^2)), but nice to take a look nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

Just out of curiosity:

```
[1,2,3,1,2,3].tap { |a| a.delete_at a.each_with_index.min.last }
#⇒ [2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Enumerable#drop_while`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-drop_while) for this purpose

```
arr = [1,2,3,1,2,3]
arr.drop_while { |i| i == arr.min }
#=> [2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: This codes removes occurrences of the minimum value from the beginning, e.g. `[1,1,2]` turns into `[2]` whereas `[2,1,1]` remains unchanged.